# Passing a Variable to an Add-in Function in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to write a for loop that takes the value of each cell, passes it into a function called `FixID()`, then outputs the result of the function into the value of the cell. The below code passes in values to the function fine, but it does not write the new value to the cell.

```
Sub test()
Total_Rows = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
For Each C In Range("A3", "C" & Total_Rows )
   C = FixID(C.Value)
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the output of `FixID`?

Comment: The output is just a string. The input is also a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Here is a quick little example I put together to test the technique, and it worked as expected...

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

Dim MyRange As Range, Cell As Range
Dim Temp As String
Dim Total_Rows As Long

Total_Rows = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

Set MyRange = Range("A1:C" & Total_Rows)
For Each Cell In MyRange
    Cell.Value = AddShrimp(Cell.Value)
Next Cell

End Sub

'Bubba Gump Function
Public Function AddShrimp(InputValue As String) As String
    AddShrimp = InputValue & " Shrimp"
End Function
```

Before: [image: before_script]

After: [image: after_script]

**ORIGINAL RESPONSE:** Make sure you define the `Range` you're going to iterate through like this:

```
For Each C In Range("A3:C" & Total_Rows)
     C.Value = FixID(C.Value)
Next C
```

I would probably add `Option Explicit` to the top of your routine as well, and declare all your variables up-front too (to prevent confusion, typo-related errors etc.):

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

Dim Total_Rows As Long
Dim C As Range, TotalRange As Range

Total_Rows = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
Set TotalRange = Range("A3:C" & Total_Rows)

For Each C In TotalRange
    C.Value = FixID(C.Value)
Next C

End Sub
```

Comment: It does not return any errors, just doesn't put the new value in the cell.

Comment: Interesting... I wrote a trivial `AddShrimp` function and it iterated right through without issue. (See my updated response above.)

Comment: Can you share more about your target worksheet and `FixID` function?

Comment: My issue was  I had `c = FixID(c.value) `. It needed to be `c.Value = FixID(c.value) `. I agree that defining variables is good practice though. Thanks for the help!